# Creating features function for further classification in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have read a description, how to apply random forest regression [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words). In this example the authors use the following code to create the features:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",max_features = 5000)
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_train_reviews)
train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()
```

I am thinking of combining several possibilities as features and turn them on and off. And I don't know how to do it.
What I have so far is that I define a class, where I will be able to turn on and off the features and see if it brings something (for example, all unigrams and 20 most frequent unigrams, it could be then 10 most frequent adjectives, tf-idf). But for now I don't understand how to combine them together. 
The code looks like this, and in the function part I am lost (the kind of function I have would replicate what they do in the tutorial, but it doesn't seem to be really helpful the way I do it):

```
class FeatureGen: #for example, feat = FeatureGen(unigrams = False) creates feature set without the turned off feature
def __init__(self, unigrams = True, unigrams_freq = True)
self.unigrams = unigrams
self.unigrams_freq = unigrams_freq

def get_features(self, input): 
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",max_features = 5000)
    tokens = input["token"]
    if self.unigrams:
        train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(tokens)
    return train_data_features
```

What should I do to add one more feature possibility? Like contains 10 most frequent words.

```
          if self.unigrams
               train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(tokens)  
          if self.unigrams_freq:
                #something else
    return features #and this should be a combination somehow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need np.hstack

However you need each features array to have one row per training case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've started looking this direction, and it seems to work with the numpy.column_stack